# Не могу получить url

Tags: java, android

В методе  onClick использую следующую структуру:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("position", position);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("items_to_parse", (ArrayList<String>) allPhoto);
allPhoto.add(0, "link");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Вставляя в поле "link" любую ссылку, открывает изображение, не совсем корректно, но сама суть.
Теперь тоже самое хочу сделать, но получая конкретный линк, а именно получая его из моей модели следующим образом:

```
allPhoto.add(imageUploads.get(position).getUrl());
```

Но выбивает ошибку, причём не могу увидеть какую, так как logcat не открывается.
Класс ImageUpload:

```
public class ImageUpload {
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;
@SerializedName("output_metadata")
@Expose
private OutputMetadata outputMetadata;
@SerializedName("handler")
@Expose
private Integer handler;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
private List<VideoUpload> videoUploads = new ArrayList<>();
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public List<VideoUpload> getVideoUploads() {
    return videoUploads;
}

public void setVideoUploads(List<VideoUpload> videoUploads) {
    this.videoUploads = videoUploads;
}

boolean loadImage = false;
String Path;

public boolean isLoadImage() {
    return loadImage;
}

public void setLoadImage(boolean loadImage) {
    this.loadImage = loadImage;
}

public String getPath() {
    return Path;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    Path = path;
}

public Boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public OutputMetadata getOutputMetadata() {
    return outputMetadata;
}

public void setOutputMetadata(OutputMetadata outputMetadata) {
    this.outputMetadata = outputMetadata;
}

public Integer getHandler() {
    return handler;
}

public void setHandler(Integer handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Код класса `VideoUpload`

```
public class VideoUpload {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("videoUrl")
@Expose
String videoUrl;
@SerializedName("user_portrait_huge")
@Expose
private String userPortraitHuge;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;

public String getUserPortraitHuge() {
    return userPortraitHuge;
}

public void setUserPortraitHuge(String userPortraitHuge) {
    this.userPortraitHuge = userPortraitHuge;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

boolean loadImage = false;

public String getVideoUrl() {
    return videoUrl;
}

public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
    this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean isLoadImage() {
    return loadImage;
}

public void setLoadImage(boolean loadImage) {
    this.loadImage = loadImage;
}
```

Код активити `FullScreenViewActivity`

```
public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity {
private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
ArrayList<String> photo = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    int position = 0;
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i != null) {
        position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        photo.addAll(getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("items_to_parse"));
    }
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    int width = size.x;
 //   int height = size.y;

    adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this, photo,width);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код класса `VideoUpload` и полный код класса `ImageUpload`.

Comment: @post_zeew обновил вопрос.

Comment: `imageUploads` – объект какого класса?

Comment: @post_zeew ImageUpload, вроде как

Comment: @post_zeew вроде как все правильно, нет?

Comment: Если `imageUploads` – объект класса `ImageUpload`, то на этапе компиляции Вы должны были получить ошибку, так как класс `ImageUpload` не содержит метода `get(...)`.

Comment: @post_zeew как не содержит если содержит?public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

Comment: Может все-таки `imageUploads` – коллекция `ArrayList<ImageUpload>`?

Comment: @post_zeew взгляните пжл на скриншот, возможно будет полезно

Comment: Не содержит. В классе `ImageUpload` определен метод `getUrl()` – метод без параметров, а Вы вызываете этот метод, передавая ему параметр.

Comment: @post_zeew как решить проблему? так как я то получаю ссылки от пользователей - это 100%
сохраняя их таким образом
setOutputMetadata(imageUpload.getOutputMetadata());

Comment: Из скриншота видно, что объект `imageUploads` – это коллекция `ArrayList<ImageUpload>`. Разберитесь с **азами** языка, тогда будет проще.

Comment: @post_zeew это не ответ. И да, я могу получать несколько ссылок сразу.

Comment: Разумеется это не ответ, так как я пишу в комментариях. Что (конкретно) возвращает метод `getUrl()` в строке `allPhoto.add(imageUploads.get(position).getUrl());`?

Comment: И покажите еще код `FullScreenViewActivity`.

Comment: @post_zeew код обновил, что возвращает не могу сказать, думал что url

Comment: Тогда покажите код адаптера `FullScreenImageAdapter`. И это, как это не можете сказать? Ну посмотрите, что у Вас находится в Вашем `imageUploads`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47516/discussion-between-inkognito-and-post-zeew).

Comment: Спасибо за приглашение, но нет. У меня осталось всего пару вопросов.

Comment: `Вставляя в поле "link" любую ссылку, открывает изображение, не совсем корректно` – скажите, какую конкретно Вы ссылку вставляете, и что значит "не совсем корректно"?

Answer (score 1):

Информации о том, какого формата ссылки содержит объект `VideoUpload` получить не удалось, поэтому ответ будет построен на предположении, что формат такой:

```
http://...
```

Коллекция `allPhoto`, содержащая такие ссылки, передается в адаптер `FullScreenImageAdapter`, которые загружает картинки по `uri`, которая формируется следующим образом

```
String uri = "https://" + StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_IMAGE + _imagePaths.get(position).toString();
```

Отсюда можно понять, что `uri` получается некорректным, так как в нем, как минимум, будет содержаться две последовательности, указывающие протокол, разделенные некоторым `StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_IMAGE`.

Проблема может быть решена, например, реализация адаптера таким образом, чтобы он не портил эти самые ссылки. Примерно как-то так:

```
String uri = _imagePaths.get(position).toString();
```

При этом, скорее всего будет необходимо переработать и другие части адаптера.